# Set C++ object file output location with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to use CMake for a project, but I have the following two requirements:

1. The final output of the project should be a set of object files (*.o).
2. The location of the object files is important.  I want to select which directory the files are outputted.

Does CMake support this type of behavior?  If so, how?  Can I do it with move commands after the object file is build?

Comment: Is your source tree split up over multiple directories? or are all your source files in the directories?

Comment: All source files are in a single directory.  The object files will need to go to a special directory for use later by a proprietary commercial software package.

Comment: This is one case where CMake is just a REALLY bad fit. 

If you must use cmake I'd run a bash or python script after to search the build tree for the .o files you are looking for, then package them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an [object library](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library).

Now the problem is that:

> Object libraries cannot be imported, exported, installed, or linked.
>   http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_library

I would try to use the [install(DIRECTORY ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall).

Using the options:

```
DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}   #Probably you have to check more precisely where the object files are built

DESTINATION    #it's something relative to DESTDIR, if set, or CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX otherwise

FILES_MATCHING

PATTERN "*.o"
```

A flaw of this solution will be in the output directory name, that will be basically decided by cmake, I wonder if anything can be done in that respect.